# How to get a SSL Certificate for a public IP

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, apache, amazon

I am using *Amazon's EC2* to host my *RDS database*. I access the database via **http** calls to the EC2 instance, which in turn contacts the database. I would like to use **https** instead to allow for a more secure connection.

I am new to the world of security. From what I have read so far, I need to get a **Certificate Authority** to validate my domain. I pay a fee and they will validate for a certain time frame.

1) Can I use my **Public DNS address** to get the SSL certificate?

2) Are there any **free CA's** that are *known as trusted* that I can use to obtain a certificate?

3)I want to use https because the EC2 instance will be handling user login. Should I go ahead and use regular **http** and send information that way instead of trying to set up https?

Any and all advice/input welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you sit on both sides of a TLS connection you can use a self signed certificate. In some conditions this is even more secure than trusting any recognized CA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) Can I use my Public DNS address to get the SSL certificate?

No; to quote [this Amazon tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html#ssl_prereq),

```
If you plan to use your EC2 instance to host a public web site, you
need to register a domain name for your web server or transfer an
existing domain name to your Amazon EC2 host.
```

The "Public DNS address" from Amazon (which looks something like `ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com`) won't work because you are not Amazon.  You need to get your own domain so that you're authorized to get certs for it.

> 2) Are there any free CA's that are known as trusted that I can use to
>   obtain a certificate?

StartSSL is the traditional answer for this, but they're [under a cloud](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2016/10/24/distrusting-new-wosign-and-startcom-certificates/) and probably don't fit what you call "trusted".

[LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is another good answer that will probably fit your needs, especially where it's you needing access to your service (and not, say, a wide customer base of varied people and browsers).

> 3)I want to use https because the EC2 instance will be handling user
>   login. Should I go ahead and use regular http and send information
>   that way instead of trying to set up https?

No, there's a hundred good reasons to use HTTPS, and very few good reasons not to.

Comment: Re 2. It is worth noting that if you only need limited access to a cert protected resource, e.g. from one or two development machines. You only really need a self-signed cert. Many people refer to these as giving less security and this is not correct. They give less *trust* but the security can be even higher than commercial certs since you have full control over the creation process. But using SSCs means finding secure ways to deliver the new root certificate. That's easy for a few machines but gets hard for many. You also have to keep the private key of the root secure - always.

Comment: Since I'm new to this I decided to go with LetsEncrypt as per the suggestions and because of how easy it is to set up. I used dot.tk to host and got the domain certified ! Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: @gowenfawr Let’s encrypt doesn’t sign public ɪᴘ.

Comment: @user2284570 no one here is talking about getting a cert for the public IP address - the "public DNS address" mentioned is the Amazon domain-branded hostname for the public IP they gave you.  (You're correct that LetsEncrypt won't issue certs for public IP addresses, but that's not relevant here.)

Answer (score 0):

Accessing your database over HTTP leaves it open to interception so it is hoped that there is no sensitive information in it nor any authentication (since you are passing your id and password in the clear over the Internet).

> 1) Can I use my Public DNS address to get the SSL certificate?

That is what you should do. UPDATE: Of course, that only works when using your own domain name - you can't do that if using an AWS domain name.

> 2) Are there any free CA's that are known as trusted that I can use to obtain a certificate?

There are some but they are limited. LetsEncrypt and StartSSL for example. The level of trust is limited though since they don't provide any background checks to prove that you are legitimate.

UPDATE: I may have been a bit negative seeming about LE. It is absolutely fine for low-trust use. A step up from a self-signed cert (though that is also fine if you can get through the issue of installing root certs to all clients). It depends on your use case though and how much trust you need to apply. Without knowing the details, I can't tell you what level of trust you need. LE certs might be fine or you might need to go to the opposite extreme of an extended validation cert.

Also note that LE certs have a very short lifespan. That means that realistically, you have to have an automated certificate renewal script in place and that does reduce the security slightly unless you do the renewal outside the server the cert is for.

> 3)I want to use https because the EC2 instance will be handling user login. Should I go ahead and use regular http and send information that way instead of trying to set up https?

**NEVER** do logins over HTTP! Again, it would mean sending sensitive data in clear text over the Internet. That just invites someone to intercept it and misuse the information.

Comment: Let's Encrypt provide the same level of trust as any other certificate authorities for domain validation certificates. They just don't issue EV (Extended validation) certificates. StartSSL may not be trusted by all browser, be careful.

Comment: No, the level of *trust* is certainly not the same. They don't do *any* checks on the validity of the claim or the claimant. The level of physical security is the same but that isn't the same as trust. Please don't confuse the two. If you present me with an HTTPS connection to your website and it has a LE cert, if I bother to check (which 99.99% of people wont of course), I will not be able to *trust* your site as I would if it had a Verisign cert where they do *some* verification checks even on standard certs.

Comment: "standard certs" doesn't exists. There is DV (Domain Validation, the most common), OV (Organization Validation) and EV (Extended validation, aka "green bar").  A DV certificate from Let's encrypt has the same level of trust of a DV certificate from Verisign. A DV certificate only certify one thing: the person who control the certificate has control over the website. OV certificates add litte check over the owner, and EV adds more checks.

Comment: @Tom, thanks for providing the explanation. I realise that LE uses a form of DV. What I've not explained very well is that *process matters* when it comes to *trust*. The largely automated processes for LE - which allows them to deliver certs for free by keeping costs to a minimum - cannot provide the same level of trust as an organisation that does DV using people, entries required in DNS, etc.

Comment: About trust the process matter, and that's why, about DV certificated, Let's Encrypt is to be **more** trusted: they have a clear documented process (see ACME) and an open source back-end (boulder). And they don't do validation by email as others may do (email validation is really weak)

Comment: @Tom, I think you need to read some of the forums on LE and the discussions about the limitations of the processes used. That isn't to say that some of the big vendors don't do things worse, I absolutely know they do! But high degrees of trust is not what LE is about. Encouraging more use of HTTPS is what LE is about.

Comment: Yes, LE is about encouraging HTTPS. That  said, it's false to say "The largely automated processes for LE [...] cannot provide the same level of trust as an organisation that does DV using people, entries required in DNS, etc."

Answer (score -2):

**For free/trial SSL certificate**, you should go with either **Symantec, Comodo or RapidSSL**. They are world's leading SSL Certificate Authorities and also accepted by 99.9% modern browsers.

Comment: They disallow static public ɪᴘs.